# Access to recorded network in device which extra security layer to set a custom wifi interface

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

I was develoment an app which create a custom wifi interface in recorded network of the device.

After a lot of trubbles and stackoverflow searching, I get into a working solution which this code:

```
if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled) {
            wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
        }
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // only for gingerbread and newer versions
            val wifiEnterpriseConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
            val wifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
            wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
            wifiEnterpriseConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
            wifiEnterpriseConfig.phase2Method = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2
            wifiEnterpriseConfig.caCertificate = null
            wifiEnterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = null
            wifiEnterpriseConfig.identity = "\"" + BuildConfig.WIFI_USER + "\""
            wifiEnterpriseConfig.password = "\"" + BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS + "\""
            wifiConfiguration.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.LEAP)
            wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig = wifiEnterpriseConfig
            wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + BuildConfig.WIFI_SSID + "\""
            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)
            wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS + "\""

            wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)

            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP)

            wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)
            wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)

            var ssid = wifiManager.addNetwork(
                wifiConfiguration
            )
            Log.d("es.paytef.wificepsamanager", "Añade la configuración: $wifiConfiguration")
            Log.d(
                "es.paytef.wificepsamanager",
                "Tras añadir a la config: ${wifiManager.configuredNetworks}"
            )
            //Enable all the interface
            wifiManager.configuredNetworks.map {
                it.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
                Log.d(
                    "es.paytef.wificepsamanager",
                    "Habilita el status de: ssid:${it.SSID} status: ${it.status}"
                )
            }
            wifiManager.disconnect()
            Log.d("es.paytef.wificepsamanager", "Habilita el wifi: $ssid")
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(ssid, true) // this initiates the connection
            Log.d("es.paytef.wificepsamanager", "Conecta el wifi: ssid:$ssid ")
            wifiManager.reconnect()
        }else {
            val config = WifiConfiguration()
            config.SSID = BuildConfig.WIFI_SSID
            config.priority = 1
            config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
            val enterpriseConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)
            config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)
            config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)
            config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
            config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)

            config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP)
            config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP)
            enterpriseConfig.identity = BuildConfig.WIFI_USER
            enterpriseConfig.password = BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS
            enterpriseConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
            enterpriseConfig.phase2Method = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2
            config.enterpriseConfig = enterpriseConfig
            val id = wifiManager.addNetwork(config)
            Log.d("es.paytef.wificepsa", "# addNetwork returned $id")

            wifiManager.configuredNetworks.map {
                it.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
            }
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true)
        }
```

regarding my ersmission configuration:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

My problem was with Android 7 device which dosen't accept the configuration, but which this version check it does.

HOWEVER, in some device like IM30, which have an extra security layer to access to remember network, this code doesn't work due to that extra security layer.

Do you know some way to configure in code that kind of access to  networks settings which have been secured with an extra password.

I know this is like look for the needle in the haystack, but it this kind of development possible? or is much more possible try to load some hack script.